# The right way to use BufferdOutputStream to write a large number of different small files

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream, bufferedoutputstream

I have a need to write a large number of different small files(about 30kb per file).Below is my java code:

```
 for(every file){
    File destFile = new File(fileName);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        // System.out.println(dr.readLine());
        bos.write(result.getBytes(
                "UTF-8"));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Of course ,for every file,I have to new a File object.But is it necessary to new fileOutputStream and  BufferdOutputStream object for every distinct file?Is there a more efficient way to write a large number of small files?

Comment: No, you can't share `FileOutputStream` between files.

Answer (score 1):

You can't share the FileOutputStream, as Sotirios says. The problem with your method is that you're creating a new File every iteration, without closing them. This may cause your program to overcome the limit of open files allowed.

On linux use:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

to read the maximum number of files you can open.

and:

```
ulimit -n unlimited
```

to remove that limit (be careful and investigate other ulimit options).

Comment: thx @Martin for the edit. Time to go to bed in Italy... 3.30 am :)

Answer (score 1):

No. If you use `FileOutputStream` wrapped into `BufferedOutputStream`, you must create both instance per file.

But if you use java 7, you can use [`Files#write(Path path, byte\[\] bytes, OpenOption... options)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write%28java.nio.file.Path,%20byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...%29) without creating both instance. This class has introduced from java 7.